# Parcel outputs multiple CSS files

Tags: parceljs

How do I configure parcel so that I get a single output CSS file?  I am using version 2, and it seems that the default is to output a separate CSS file to dist for each stylesheet referenced in the HTML file.  For instance, with this test.html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./a.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./b.css">
 </head>
</html>
```

running parcel build test.html outputs two css files under "dist".  Is there a way to make it output one combined file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@import` at-rule to combine multiple css files into a single bundle (see [documentation](https://parceljs.org/languages/css/#%40import)).

For example, you could have an `index.css` with this content:

```css
@import "a.css";
@import "b.css";
```

...and then reference `index.css` in your `index.html` file:

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
 </head>
</html>
```

See [this example repo](https://github.com/astegmaier/parcel-css-imports-test).

**Edit:**

Another way to achieve this goal, if your app uses javascript, is to do the css imports from a javascript file. So your html file would look like this:

```js
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
 </head>
</html>
```

...and your index.js file would look like this:

```js
import "./a.css";
import "./b.css";
// The rest of your app...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This works, and is the approach I eventually found after posting my question.  I seems like a work-around, though.   I was hoping there might be some configuration option.  However, it is not much effort for me to change to doing things this way.  I will probably mark this "accepted" but will wait a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I added another way to do this through JavaScript. I also poked around the parcel source code, and I'm not sure that there's a way to do this out-of-the-box through config alone. It would be possible if you wrote a custom `bundler` plugin, but that seems like overkill.